# Prove dependency of variables in a Bayes net (CS188)

Tags: conditional-probability, bayesian-network

I'm trying to understand how the conclusion of $P(x|z)=1, \forall x = z$ is reached.
I can understand it intuitively but I'm having a big trouble figuring out how to really 'chug the math'.

I've been noodling with CPT's and trying to juggle things algebraically but can't seem to reach the conclusion that $P(X|Z) \ne P(X)$.

How to approach a 'proof' of this statement? Here is a screenshot from the lecture:

[image: Screenshot from the lecture]

Comment: I'll clarify more:

I understand why this is a 'deterministic' assignment of the probabilities.
If $X$ is fully dependent on $Y$, and $Z$ is fully dependent of $Y$, it makes sense that $X$ is dependent on $Z$.

My issue is that I cannot arrive *algebraically* to the conclusion that $P(x|z)=1$ if $x=z$, no matter the amount of manipulation I do. 

*Logically* it's pretty obvious but I wish there was a set of rigorous moves I could do to arrive the same conclusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prove the statement on the slide, we need to combine these points:

- $X, Y$, and $Z$ are binary variables.
- $P(X|Y) = 1$ if $x = y$, and $0$ otherwise.
- $P(Z|Y) = 1$ if $z = y$, and $0$ otherwise.
- The Bayesian network implies $P(X,Y,Z) = P(Y)P(X|Y)P(Z|Y)$

So now let's see what we know about $P(Z|X)$. I'll look at the case $P(Z = 1 | X = 1)$ but the same algebra can be used for the other possibilities.

Using the definition of conditional probability we see

$P(Z = 1|X = 1) = \frac{P(X = 1,Z = 1)}{P(X = 1)} = \frac{\sum_{y = 0}^1 P(X = 1,Y = y, Z = 1)}{P(X = 1)} = $
$\frac{\sum_{y = 0}^1 P(Y = y)P(X = 1|Y = y)P(Z = 1 | Y = y)}{P(X = 1)} = $
$\frac{P(Y = 0) * 0 + P(Y = 1)*1}{P(X = 1)} = \frac{P(Y = 1)}{P(X = 1)}$.

Now we can use

$P(X = 1) = \sum_{y = 0}^1 P(X = 1 | Y = y) P(Y = y)  = $
$P(Y = 0) * 0 + P(Y = 1) * 1 = P(Y = 1)$

So we end up with the conclusion

$P(Z = 1 | X = 1) = \frac{P(Y = 1)}{P(X = 1)} = \frac{P(Y = 1)}{P(X = 1)} = \frac{P(Y = 1)}{P(Y = 1)} = 1$.

Similarly we can show $P(Z = 0|X = 0) = 1$

and as a consequence we get

$P(Z = 0 | X = 1) = P(Z = 1 | X = 0) = 0$.

So we see that $X$ and $Z$ are not independent.

Comment: No worries, glad I could help! :-)

Answer (score 0):

congrats for posting your first question :)
Here's my attempt at proving the statement: by chain rule you can write

$P(X|Z) = P(X|Y)P(Y|Z)$

and using Bayes' rule $P(Y|Z) = P(Z|Y)\frac{P(Y)}{P(Z)}$, and by virtue of $P(X|Y)=\delta_{xy}$ and $P(Z|Y)=\delta_{zy}$ we can write

$P(X|Z) = P(X|Y)P(Z|Y)\frac{P(Y)}{P(Z)} = \delta_{xy}\delta_{zy}\frac{P(Y)}{P(Z)} = \delta_{xz}\frac{P(Y)}{P(Z)}$

Here you can see that $P(X|Z)$ depends on $Z$ and therefore $X$ is dependent on $Z$

Comment: My answer feels a little untidy. I would have expected $P(X|Z) = \delta_{xz}$ without the marginal distributions over Y and Z. I hope to stand corrected :)

Comment: Thanks for the 'grats :)

I'm embarrassed to ask this, but how come $P(X|Z)=P(X|Y)P(Y|Z)$ follows from the chain rule?

Comment: I'm trying to follow through the proof now, but I've noticed there was no use of the joint probability distribution induced by the Bayes net itself:

$P(X, Y, Z) = P(Y)P(X|Y)P(Z|Y)$

Comment: As I said, shaky answer :D thanks for poking holes in it. I think that chain rules implies $P(X|Z) = \Sigma_Y P(X|Y)P(Y|Z)$ so I was missing a summation sign. I am still not addressing the other problems because I don't have time right now, will go over it later :)